# How to perform MINUS in MySQL (5.5) between two SQL queries and delete the resulting rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

How to **perform MINUS in MySQL (5.5) between two SQL queries**. I am not good with SQL.

What I want is that only fetch the keys which do not exist in second query.
I am **trying to use LEFT JOIN** to accomplish this. Can I use something like this:

```
     SELECT  target.component_id, target.asset_code FROM 
         (SELECT comp_files.* FROM stageSchema.components comp
             INNER JOIN productionSchema.component_files comp_files
             ON comp.id = comp_files.component_id) target
     LEFT JOIN 
         (SELECT comp_files.* FROM stageSchema.components comp
             INNER JOIN stageSchema.component_files comp_files
             ON comp.id = comp_files.component_id) stage
     ON target.component_id = stage.component_id
     WHERE stage.component_id IS NULL;
```

I know the above query is not proper. Any ideas how to do this ?

The structure for "**component_files**" table is :

```
    CREATE TABLE `component_files` (
     `component_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `asset_code` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
     `file_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
     `file_size` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `video_size` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `bit_rate` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
     `last_updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
     UNIQUE KEY `cf_uk` (`component_id`,`asset_code`) USING BTREE,
     CONSTRAINT `cf_comp_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`component_id`) REFERENCES `components` (`id`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here are the results of EXPLAIN

Without WHERE clause :
[image]

With WHERE clause :
[image]

Comment: whatever you do, don't subselect inside an `IN()` statement.
Use `WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT....)`

Comment: Shouldn't the first inner select have `FROM productionSchema.components` instead of `FROM stageSchema.components`?

Comment: @Galz, I've tried the individual queries and then did MINUS using PHP.
I know it's a bad technique, but it works as expected. How to accomplish this using pure SQL

Comment: What happens when you run the query you posted? Does it give an error, not return any results or returns wrong results?

Comment: from my pov the query should work as expected if the db names are correct

Comment: @Galz, the query timeouts.
If WHERE clause is removed then reply is sent back within 40 seconds with data. The table has about 443693 rows.
The difference in two schemas (stageSchema.component_files and productionSchema.component_files) is of one row only. I've verified this using PHP.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you run EXPLAIN for the full query with and without the `WHERE` clause and post both results? Sounds very weird that applying the `WHERE` clause causes a timeout.

Comment: @Galz I've added screen shots to the question.

Comment: @ManmohanBishnoi - I must say I am perplexed... Looks like both queries should have similar run times. Long shot - can you try replacing the `WHERE` with `HAVING stage.component_id IS NULL`. Note that in order to try this you would have to add `stage.component_id` to the `SELECT` clause as well..

Comment: @Galz, Still no luck :(
Time out occurs with HAVING.
I am going with my PHP workaround for now. Anyways thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks correct. The reasons for the inefficiency could be missing indexes in the 2 tables that you haven't provided their design and MySQL optimizer not producing efficient plan because of the derived tables.

Try to write the query without derived tables, with joins only:

```
 SELECT 
     target.component_id, target.asset_code 
 FROM 
     stageSchema.components comp
   INNER JOIN 
     productionSchema.component_files target
       ON comp.id = target.component_id
   LEFT JOIN 
     stageSchema.component_files stage
       ON comp.id = stage.component_id
 WHERE 
     stage.component_id IS NULL;
```